# Looking for repo and package for opendkim on debian 8 (Jessie)

Tags: debian, opendkim

I know that debian 8 (Jessie) is deprecated, but I have a debian 8 server that cannot be upgraded in the near future. I'm keeping that server running, and for the most part, so far, so good.

However ... I'd like to install the `opendkim` and `opendkim-tools` packages on this server, and I can't find those packages in any `apt` repos.

Does anyone know of any 3rd-party `apt` repo from which I could obtain the debian 8 packages for `opendkim` and `opendkim-tools`?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you considered building it from source? There are releases from around the time of Debian 8 on Github.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have tried that, but due to the out-dated-ness of my debian 8 host, there are a few packages needed for the build which I cannot install via `apt`, either. I could go and try to build those packages from source, as well, but it's a lot of work to do all of this software building, and I'm hoping I can instead find a repo where I can get `opendkim` and `opendkim-tools`, because that would be much quicker and easier. But yes, I'll eventually bite the bullet and undertake the build, if no repo can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a suitable repo for `opendkim` for Jessie:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free
```

It gives me a warning about the repo contents being unverified, but that doesn't matter to me.

And now, after installing `opendkim` from that repo, I have it working on my host.